On the solvability of a nonlinear integral equation
Consider the integral equation
\begin{equation}
\phi(t)=\int_{t}^{\infty} f(s)\exp\left(-\int_{t}^{t+s} \ln\left(1+\frac{K\phi(u)+\eta(u)}{\phi(u)}\right)du\right)ds\tag{1}
\end{equation}
for a constant $K\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and continuously differentiable functions $f,\eta:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. When $\eta=0$, we have the straightforward solution
\begin{equation}
\phi(t)=\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{f(s)}{(1+K)^{s}}\mathop{ds}.
\end{equation}
For small $\eta(u)\ll \phi(u)$, we can approximate
\begin{equation}
\ln\left(1+K+\frac{\eta(u)}{\phi(u)}\right)\sim \ln(1+K)+\frac{\eta(u)}{(1+K)\phi(u)}.
\end{equation}
It follows that
\begin{equation}
\phi(t)\sim\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{f(s)}{(1+K)^s}\exp\left(-\int_{t}^{t+s}\frac{\eta(u)}{(1+K)\phi(u)}\mathop{du}\right)\mathop{ds}.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
We can also write $\exp(-z)\sim 1-z$ for small $z$, so that
\begin{align}
\phi(t)\sim\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{f(s)}{(1+K)^s}\mathop{ds}-\int_{t}^{\infty}\int_{t}^{t+s}\frac{f(s)\eta(u)}{(1+K)^{s+1}\phi(u)}\mathop{du}\mathop{ds}.\tag{3}
\end{align}
Does $(1)$, $(2)$, or $(3)$ admit a mathematical expression for $\phi$ in terms of $f$ and $\eta$ only? Can any of the more complicated forms be solved numerically (i.e. to compare against the analytical solution if one for $(1)$ doesn't exist)?

Which problem leads to equation (1)?

@Gribouillis A problem whereby I consider continuously discounted free cash flows $f$ to a firm with enterprise value $\phi$. The mess in the logarithm is an expression for the continuously varying discount rate in terms of $\phi$ (using WACC).

Putting $u = \frac{1}{k}$, the limits become finite, so maybe differentiation under the integral sign helps? Moreover, I am not sure but if $ \phi(u) < \eta(u) $ then expanding using the natural logarithms power series up to a quadratic (or even linear term) should yield something solvable. Do you have any idea how $\eta(u)$ will look like?

@Kraken We can set $\eta(u)=\eta$ to a constant for now. It will be fairly stable, but oscillates in reality.

I see, give me some time. If it oscillates, then could one assume it's a sinusoidal curve?

@Kraken Yes you could do $\eta(u)=\eta_0+\epsilon \sin\omega u$
